# Binary Search with few modification

Tags: c++, c++11

While I am trying to compile the code with few modification in binary search recursive function. The program is acting weird. Some time it gives the correct value  and some time it goes to infinite loop. Please explain what went wrong with the code. I am using DEV C++ as an IDE.

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

//function to compare the two integers
int compare(int low, int high) 
{
    if (low==high)
        return 0;
    if (low<high)
        return 1;
    else 
        return -1;
}

//Function for binary search using recursion
int *BinarySearch(int *Arr,int Val,int start,int end)
{
    int localstart=start;
    int localend=end;
    int mid=(start+end)/3;
    cout<<"MID:"<<mid;
    int comp= compare(Val,Arr[mid]);
    if(comp==0)
        return &(Arr[mid]);
    else if (comp>0)
        return BinarySearch(Arr,Val,localstart,mid-1);
    else 
        return BinarySearch(Arr,Val,mid+1,localend);
    return NULL;
}

main()
{
    int *arr;
    arr= new int [256];
    string str;
    getline(cin,str);
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<str;
    int index=0;
    while(ss>>arr[index])
        {index++;}
    //cout<<arr[index-1];
    cout<<"Enter Value:";
    int value;
    cin>>value;
    int *final;
    final=BinarySearch(arr,value,0,index-1);
    if(final!=NULL)
        cout<<"Final:"<<*final;
    else
        cout<<"Not Found";
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the program?

Comment: A bit hard to read with the lack of indentation.

Comment: "Some time it gives the correct value and some time it goes to infinite loop"....What are the input values in both the scenarios?

Comment: I do love questions that state "The program is acting weird" and "Some time it gives the correct value and some time it goes to infinite loop. " without given the inputs. Then asking use to "Please explain what went wrong with the code". My answer would be along the lines - when not formulate a question based on doing a bit of debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. What should `BinarySearch` do if `Val` is not in the array?  Trace out what your code does in this case.
2. `(start+end)/3` probably isn't the middle of the current range.

Comment: Hello Nate, The problem was to modify the binary search so that it can divide the problem into 1/3 and 2/3 of the subarrays so I  am not searching for middle element exactly. Sorry poor indentation... Moreover if the Val is not in BinarySearch it will return NULL as other condition are handled above

Comment: @AvikDas: Are you *sure* that your function will return NULL if the value is not found?  Do a short example by hand, pretending to be the computer and following your algorithm, to see if you ever get to the last line of your function.